# Convert UTC time to user locale time

Tags: login, timezone

I want to display the users previous log in time. I created a query for it and this gives me the right field. But this always shows UTC time and not the user locale. I do need to show it in the users locale timezone. How do I show it in the users locale?

```
@AuraEnabled
 public static LoginHistory getLoginHistory() {

    List<LoginHistory> secondLogin = [ SELECT   LoginTime 
    FROM    LoginHistory 
    WHERE   userId = :UserInfo.getUserId() 
    ORDER BY LoginTime DESC 
    LIMIT   1
    OFFSET  1];
    return ( secondLogin == null || secondLogin.isEmpty() )
    ? null
    : secondLogin.get( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that it is an AuraEnabled method so I assume that you are using a Lightning Component to display the information?

If so the following will display to the user the Date Time in their timezone

```
<ui:outputDateTime value="{![valueProvider | iteration variable].LoginTime}" 
     timeZone="{!$Locale.timezone}" 
     format="{!$Locale.datetimeFormat}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to use UserInfo class's getTimeZone() method:

> getTimeZone()
>
> Returns the current user’s local time zone.

and then convert according to the timezone, you can leverage the [TimeZone Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm) for the offset and converting accordingly. not sure if there is another approach though (a better one =P).